# Getting dialog to display one time after installation

Tags: android

I am trying to get my dialog in my application to display only one time after the application has been installed and allow me to elaborate more.  After the user installs the application and launches it for the first time a dialog will popup but after the user click the ok button to dismiss the dialog.  That will be the last time user will ever see that dialog again unless he or she deletes the application and installs it again.  I would like to use this for my application and if this method describe requires code to my dialog, I would like if somebody could assist me with my code below. If you can offer any help that would make me really happy. If not can somebody point towards a tutorial so I can further my knowledge.

```
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    alertDialog.setMessage("Message1");

    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        }
     });

    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store a value when the dialog is dismissed for the first time, and check if that value exists every time your application starts:

```
final SharedPreferences prefs=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);//this==context
if(!prefs.contains("FirstTime")){
     //Other dialog code
     alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putBoolean("FirstTime",true);
            editor.commit();
            //more code....
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: `if(!prefs.contains("FirstTime"))` would be better. And `prefs.putBoolean("FirstTime",true);` should be changed to `editor.putBoolean("FirstTime",true);`.